# Is it possible to create a nested LinkedObject [Java]

Tags: java, object, linked-list, singly-linked-list, doubly-linked-list

`LinkedObject`s aren't a thing, but I called it that because I'm wanting it to mimic the behavior of a LinkedList.

What I'm specifically trying to figure out is whether it's possible to create an `Object` that is a `String` and a reference to the proceeding object, from an array of strings. This would be used to form a chain of custody where each person that handles a piece of evidence is only aware of who they passed the evidence on to.

So, let's say I had 5 individuals who passed evidence to each other:

"Fred", "Jake", "Jane", "Beth", "Zog"

From that array of strings, I would want to create something that looked like this:

Name: Fred
Object: Jake
    Name: Jake
    Object: Jane
        Name: Jane
        Object Beth
            Name: Beth
            Object: Zog
                Name: Zog
                Object: null

---

I'm asking this because I've made many attempts to figure this out to no avail. I don't have code to provide because my attempts have failed. I've done my best to find some kind of answer to this question.

Comment: Not sure on a data structure level how you can really enforce the "only" part in the "each person that handles a piece of evidence is only aware of who they passed the evidence on to". Even if you come up with some kind of linked structure, it only takes one more reference to get to the guy next to the next guy, right?

Comment: I'm not sure if the crime scene example is the use case or just a way to describe the problem. If it's the use case, I suppose it's possible to extend ```LinkedObject``` for each person to hide the next reference.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.

```
    class LinkedObject {
        final String name;
        LinkedObject next;

        LinkedObject(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    LinkedObject createLinkedList(List<String> names) {
        LinkedObject head = null;

        ListIterator<String> it = names.listIterator(names.size() - 1);
        while(it.hasPrevious()) {
            if(head == null) head = new LinkedObject(it.previous());
            else {
                LinkedObject o = new LinkedObject(it.previous());
                o.next = head;
                head = o;
            }
        }

        return head;
    }
```

We're creating a class, `LinkedObject` which contains a String field, storing data, and a reference to the next `LinkedObject`. The first `LinkedObject` is called the "head" of the linked list, and describes the entire list. This is a [singly linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Singly_linked_list).

From your example, if you have the 'beth' object from your list, you can find the 'zog' object from the value of beth.next, and so on.